# How to check from which network and VPN the device is connected to, in electron application windows/mac?

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I have one situation where my electron application needs to check if the user is connected to any VPN network or not. I have check NPM middlewares and electron features but unable to find anything helpful. Is there any way to get the following information from electron application:

1> Is device (windows/mac) is connected to VPN?

(My comment: I have already tried Window.navigator, it only shows a status of the connection, online: offline ? I have also tried ipcMain and ipcRenderer ['online-status-changed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729032/is-where-a-way-to-listen-to-wireless-network-changes-in-node-js))

2> If the user is connected to a VPN network, I need network information.

If you have any information, how to collect this data within electron app, Please share it.

Comment: Have you tried the package 'ip'?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible to complete accurately, any address could be from a VPN and they could change anytime. Popular ways to combat this is checking their IP address against a database of known IPs used by popular VPNs. I will list some popular ones below, though they can be abused by the client and possibly cause some charges to your account. For a more detailed answer, you should check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/33446886/9189336.

- https://vpnblocker.net/
- https://getipintel.net/